# Appx build-issue in electron-builder when using special character in publisherDisplayName

Tags: electron-builder

The microsoft account of my company requires to have the "&" in the publisher displayname but I have no way of getting it to work with an error....

I already tried \&, &amp and \u0026 so far without success. If I remove the "&" it build fine but the Microsoft store complains about the missmatch.

My config:

```
  appx: {
    publisherDisplayName: '***** Software and Solutions GmbH & Co. KG',
    identityName: '********.**********',
publisher: 'CN=**********'
  },
```

It results in the following error:

```
MakeAppx : error: Package creation failed.
MakeAppx : error: 0x80080204 - The specified package format is not valid: The package manifest is not v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing the & with &

(It will end up in the minifest-xml which has trouble with the special character)